# 8086 program to read the DOB of a user and determine the age

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

This is my 8086 `.COM` file code:

```
org 100h                       ;tells the assembler that the code that follows should be placed at offset 1000H
.MODEL SMALL                ;Determies the size of code and data pointers
.STACK 100h                 ;Tells the size of the stack
.DATA                       ;Separates variable declaration  
  ;Messages to be displayed
  Message1 DB   "Enter your Full name: $"      
  Message2 DB   "Enter your date of birth : $" 
  Messagee3 DB  "Enter the current date : $"     
.CODE

Main PROC                       ;Beginning of the Main Procedure
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax 
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, OFFSET Message1
    int 21h
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h
    mov bl, al
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, 0dh            
    int 21h            
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h 
    mov ah, 9h
    mov dx, OFFSET Message2
    int 21h
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h
    mov bl, al
    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, 0dh            
    int 21h            
    mov dl, 0ah        
    int 21h   
    mov dl, bl
    mov ah, 0ah
    mov ah, 4ch                ;the program to exit immediately
    int 21h                    ;The standard way to call the interrupt handler 0x21         
Main ENDP                      ;denotes the end of the procedure

END Main                       ;denotes the end of the program, Main.

ret                            ;transfers control to the return address located on the stack.
```

Comment: Please i need help with this code. The Problem is to get the name from the user and the DOB and then determine the age and also printing again the name and age of the user

Comment: I seriously improved the formatting of your code. Next time, do it yourself, please.

Comment: Please specify what is actually not working for you. Have you written this code?

Comment: yes I wrote the code but I don't know assembly language and the part that deals with getting the date of birth and determining the age are the confusing part

Answer (score -1):

You seem to use DOS function **AH=0Ah** to get input from keyboard, but first you have to reserve a memory variable where the data will be stored. Its address should be put to **DS:DX**, see http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm

Keep on mind that the number obtained from keyboard are decimal digits (string) which needs to be converted to binary before you can make some arithmetics with them. And the result of subtraction (your age in binary) you have to convert to string of digits before they can be displayed in console.

Split your homework to series of macros of calling instructions: start with 
*CALL Initialization* and *CALL Termination*, write code of those procedures and then keep adding more procedures: WritePrompt, ReadInput, DecimalToBinary, BinaryToDecimal.

You can look into macrolibraries [dosapi](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/dosapi.htm#StdInput)
and [cpuext16](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/cpuext16.htm#LodD) if you need an inspiration.
This is how would the code look in EuroAssembler:

```
Peace16 PROGRAM FORMAT=COM
             INCLUDE dosapi.htm, cpuext16.htm
    Main::   PROC
              StdOutput ="Enter your Full name: "
              StdInput FullName
              StdOutput ="Enter the year of your birth: "
              StdInput  BirthYear
              StdOutput ="Enter this year: "
              StdInput ThisYear
              LodD BirthYear  ; Convert the string of digits to binary number in AX.
              MOV BX,AX       ; Temporary save the converted birth year.
              LodD ThisYear   ; Convert the string of digits to binary number in AX.
              SUB AX,BX       ; Compute the difference.
              StoD Age        ; Convert binary number in AX to string of digits in Age.
              StdOutput ="Hi ",FullName,=" you are now ",Age,=" years old."
              TerminateProgram
    FullName  DB 32*BYTE
    BirthYear DB 6*BYTE
    ThisYear  DB 6*BYTE
    Age       DB 4*BYTE
             ENDP
            ENDPROGRAM
```

BTW ask you teacher to switch from 16bit DOS code to 32bits, it is easier, more useful  and you won't have to bother with emulators.
Your program in 32bit Windows version would look like here:

```
Peace32 PROGRAM FORMAT=PE,ENTRY=Main::
         INCLUDE winapi.htm, cpuext32.htm
Main::    PROC
           StdOutput ="Enter your Full name: "
           StdInput FullName
           StdOutput ="Enter the year of your birth: "
           StdInput BirthYear
           StdOutput ="Enter this year: "
           StdInput ThisYear
           LodD BirthYear  ; Convert the string of digits to binary number in EAX.
           MOV EBX,EAX      ; Temporary save the converted birth year.
           LodD ThisYear   ; Convert the string of digits to binary number in EAX.
           SUB EAX,EBX     ; Compute the difference.
           StoD Age        ; Convert binary number in EAX to string of digits in Age.
           StdOutput ="Hi ",FullName,=" you are now ",Age,=" years old."
           TerminateProgram
          ENDP
FullName  DB 32*BYTE
BirthYear DB 6*BYTE
ThisYear  DB 6*BYTE
Age       DB 4*BYTE
        ENDPROGRAM
```